# How can I login (send text) with minicom?

Tags: serial-port

I am attempting to login from a Linux client to a set top box running Linux via a USB to serial cable. When I power on the device, I can see the init messages scroll past, and I get to the login prompt, like this:

> (none) login:

but I cannot login. The cursor stops flashing as if it is receiving input, but there is no response.

My serial port setup is:

> Device: /dev/ttyUSB0
>
> Bps: 115200 8N1
>
> Hardware Flow Control: Yes
>
> Software Flow Control: No

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing either your set-top box or your cable, I would first try disabling hardware flow control, since the set top probably doesn't implement it.  Essentially your Linux client is waiting for an "OK to send" signal that it will never receive because there's no physical wire in the set top to send it.

Comment: Excellent stuff - that did it. Thanks be to you, sir.

Comment: Awesome! I have just had that problem doing remote connection using vpn to linux vm and then minicom to a hardware from that linux! Hardware Flow Contol was the problem! Thx!